# Checkbox should saved and retrieved after closing the app, i tried it with sharedpreferences but it doesnt work and i dont know why

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, savechanges

I am a beginner at android development and I tried to implement a class who save a checkbox with the sharedpreferences. It works so far that I can see everything and check the checkbox in the emulator. But The click on the Save Button crashes my application. Maybe there is a fault with the TextView?

heres the code...

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    CheckBox checkBox;
    TextView textView;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settingslayout);

        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        loadSavedPreferences();
    }

    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
        if (checkBoxValue) {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }


    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
        if (checkBox.isChecked())
            textView.setText("Visited.");
        else
            textView.setText("Not Visited");


finish();

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a textview whose id is textView1 in your layout. Also why are you setting the text if you intend to finish the activity.

Comment: Thank You! That was my fault... shame on me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the finish() from OnClick(View v)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
    if (checkBox.isChecked())
        textView.setText("Visited.");
    else
        textView.setText("Not Visited");

}
```

if you have "real crash" attach the logcat.

Comment: Thank You! The finish() from OnClick was the second fault!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
           if (checkBox.isChecked())
              textView.setText("Visited.");
           else
              textView.setText("Not Visited");
           finish(); 
        }
    }
```